# How to install spek on arch linux

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux

I want to install spek but I see no instructions here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=38001 and I am a linux noob. I tried downloading the tarball and run the spek.install.txt by

chmod +x spek.install

sh -e spek.install

but nothing happens, meaning the blind shot had no effect. What do i do exactly? Also the package is not to be found through pacman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is to be installed like all AUR packages, you can find detailed info [on the Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository).

For the moment, download the package to a directory, extract it:

```
  tar -xfvz spek.tar.gz
```

then move into the newly created directory:

```
  cd spek
```

Now resolve dependencies

```
  makepkg -s
```

which will create a file spek-something-or-other.tar.xz. This file can now be installed via pacman:

```
   sudo pacman -U spek-someting-or-other.tar.xz
```

Next time, pls RTM